# Clipping DataSet leaves pixel outside of desired Polygon

Tags: python, rioxarray

I'm trying to use the clipping from rioxarray to focus on a ROI defined by a bounding box, using the following code :

```
from shapely.geometry import box

ds = ...

# Clip the Dataset
geodf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
   geometry=[box(*config.case_study.geometry)],
   crs="EPSG:4326",
)
ds = ds.rio.clip(geodf.geometry.values, geodf.crs, drop=True)

# Get relevant DataArray
da = ds[...][...]
geometry = geodf.to_crs(da.rio.crs).geometry.values[0]

# Plotting
ax = plt.subplot()
da.plot(ax=ax)
ax.plot(
   *geometry.exterior.xy,
   color="red",
   linewidth=3,
)

plt.show()
```

However, the result keeps pixels (both with nodata and actual values) outside of the area defined by the polygon (in red in the following image). It also doesn't quite clip to the geometry's extent.

[image]

I've also checked, and the polygon is indeed the only geometry defined in my GeoDataFrame.

Weirdly, clipping the selected DataArray using the same geometry (after the Dataset has already been clipped) only selects a small rectangle in the bottom right corner of the image.

I'm getting pretty puzzled trying to understand the issue